# Java 8 - Compare multiple fields in different order using Comparator

Tags: java, list, java-8, comparator

I like to use Java 8 `Comparator` to sort a `List` of an object based on three properties. The requirement is to sort in this order - Name ascending, Age descending, City ascending. If I use `reversed()` on `Age it reverses previously sorted entries as well. Here is what I've tried:

```
Comparator.comparing((Person p) -> p.getName())
          .thenComparingInt(p -> p.getAge())
          .reversed()
          .thenComparing(p -> p.getCity());
```

Comment: Is `e.getAge()` a typo ? And instead of it should be `p.getAge()` ?

Comment: It should be p.getAge(). The question is edited with typo fix.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `Comparator.reverseOrder()`:

```
.thenComparing(Person::getAge, Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

If you want to avoid autoboxing, you can do

```
.thenComparing((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p2.getAge(), p1.getAge()))
```

Or

```
.thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed())
```

Comment: just curious what is the difference ?

Comment: @YCF_L `reversed()` reverses the entire preceding chain.

Comment: I prefer the last option. Probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Like [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v), I find the third option the best (in terms of readability + performance).

Comment: How to handle NULL values for name and age while comparing based on multiple fields

Comment: @ALI  See `Comparator.nullsFirst()` and `nullLast()`.

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to use the method [`Comparator::reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--). Since you want to reverse the comparison based on the integer, just negate the age `-p.getAge()` and it will be sorted in the descending order:

```
Comparator.comparing((Person p) -> p.getName())
          .thenComparingInt(p -> -p.getAge())
          .thenComparing(p -> p.getCity());
```

Comment: Nice one... unless you happen to be -2147483648 years old. :P

Comment: @shmosel Integer.signum might help.

Comment: Theoretically nice but practically it's much easier to miss the minus sign when reading such code. Therefore I'd recommend using [shmosel's third solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565461/2032415).

Comment: Accepted @shmodel's answer as correct one as it generally answers how to approach such sort/comparison.

Comment: @Nikolas The remark about `Integer.MIN_VALUE` wasn't mine ;) As for the proposed minus+comment solution: I used to write code like that, but now I avoid it. Now, I definitely favor self-explanatory code over commented code because code cannot (at least not easily) lie, while comments can. Moreover, such a comment introduces two "sources of truth", and everybody modifying such code has to update both. Too many times have I seen that someone modified the code but forgot to update/delete such a comment. Here's [a nice read about commenting](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments/).